# Change angular directive whenever a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, angularjs, haml

I have here a button html with a directive `profile-unlink`. I want to change the directive that was set into `profile-link` after clicking the button. Would that be possible in angular js?

Code in haml:

From:

```
%button.unlink{"ff-profile-unlink" => "true"} Unlink Facebook
```

To:

```
%button.unlink{"ff-profile-link" => "true"} Link Facebook
```

Comment: Rather than changing the directive, can you just change a variable in the directive scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to have two buttons and show/hide them based on your application state, using `ng-show` and `ng-hide`. Foer example:

```
%button.unlink{"ff-profile-unlink" => "true", "ng-show" => "linked_to_facebook", "ng-click" => "unlink_facebook"} Unlink Facebook
%button.unlink{"ff-profile-link" => "true", "ng-hide" => "linked_to_facebook", "ng-click"="link_facebook"} Link Facebook
```

and then

```
function SomeCtrl ($scope) {
  $scope.link_facebook: function() { $scope.linked_to_facebook = true},
  $scope.unlink_facebook: function() { $scope.linked_to_facebook = false},
}
```

Another way is to use CSS to achieve the same result. The logic here is to have two buttons and hide/show one each time, using CSS. Here is an example:

```
%div#links
    %button.unlink{"ff-profile-unlink" => "true"} Unlink Facebook
    %button.link{"ff-profile-link" => "true"} Link Facebook
```

and in your SASS:

```
.linked_to_facebook {
    .link { display: hidden}
    .unlink {display: block}
}
.unlinked_from_facebook {
    .link { display: block}
    .unlink {display: hidden}
}
```

Then you would use `addClass` and `removeClass` to add and remove the `linked_to_facebook` and `unlinked_from_facebook` to `#links` div.

P.S: The code above can be improved. It is just to show the point.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks! Used your CSS approach. hehe

Answer (score 1):

The first comment is correct, just make one function that does 2 things.

```
%button.unlink{"ff-profile-linked-setter" => "true"}

%button.unlink{"ff-profile-linked-setter" => "false"}
```